# Puppet Agent Could not retrieve catalog

Tags: puppet

I installed Maven module in Master machine using this command:

```
puppet module install maestrodev-maven --version 1.4.0
```

It installed it successfully in /etc/puppet/modules/

Afterwards I added following code inside the file /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp of master machine

```
node 'test02.edureka.com'
{
include maven
}
```

Now, when I run below command on Puppet Agent machine

```
puppet agent -t
```

It gives error:

```
root@test02:~# puppet agent -t
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: execution expired
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': execution expired
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://test01.edureka.com/pluginfacts: execution expired
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': execution expired
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://test01.edureka.com/plugins: execution expired
Info: Loading facts
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute
Could not retrieve fact='maven_version', resolution='': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: execution expired
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: execution expired
root@test02:~#
```

puppet.conf file on master:

[image]

puppet.conf file on agent:

[image]

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is the FQDN of your puppet agent also test02.edureka.com?

Comment: Yes it is test02.edureka.com

Comment: What if you put your code inside a default node block - does it still fail?

Comment: I'll try and update.

Comment: What are the Puppet versions on the master and agent machines?  Is the agent pointing to the right master?  Can it in fact *reach* the master? Is the master running?  Do the master's logs show anything useful?

Comment: @AlexHarvey with default node also, result is same.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Master & Agent both are v3.8.7. Agent is pointing correctly to master. Master is running. Where can I see the master's logs?

Comment: The log location is configurable, but you might find the master's logs in `/var/log/puppet`.  You might also find some or all of its log messages in the general-purpose `/var/log/messages`, or in some other configured place.

Comment: I see only some info but nothing related to errors. [2017-12-19 18:49:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1547 port=8140
[2017-12-20 19:46:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-12-20 19:46:51] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
[2017-12-20 19:46:51] INFO
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 5 (0x5)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=Puppet CA: harish-virtualbox
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 11 11:02:35 2016 GMT
            Not After : Dec 11 11:02:35 2021 GMT